# Job total only showing sum of whole numbers

Tags: javascript

Here is a JSBin to what I am working with... http://jsbin.com/duwiji/3/edit

It will get the two vinyl costs. The issue is that it will only add the whole numbers and display that in the Total Job Cost Field.

**note** The error is in Job Total... the total for a 9 x 33 should be $38.61 however it gives $37.00.

Any Ideas??

**Here is the HTML**

```
<p>Enter dimensions and tab through</p>

Dimensions <input type="text" id="dim01"  onkeyup="multiplyDim();" />
&nbsp; X &nbsp;
<input type="text" id="dim02"  onkeyup="multiplyDim();" />
<br>

= <input type="text" id="sqIn1" value="- - -" /> Sq. In.
<br />1st Color X .08/sq. in. = <input type="text" id="1clr-Cost"      onfocus="multiplyCost01();" />
<br />Additional Colors <input type="text" id="qtyClrs"  onkeyup="multiply();" /> X .05 =     <input type="text" id="2clr-Cost"  onfocus="multiplyCost02();" /><br />
<p>$37.00 <!-- HERE --></p>

Job Total = $<input type="text" id="JobCost"  onfocus="sumJob();" /><br />
```

**Here is the JS**

```
function multiplyDim() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('dim01').value;
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('dim02').value;

    var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('sqIn1').value = result;
    }
}

function multiplyCost01() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('sqIn1').value;

    var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * 0.08;
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('1clr-Cost').value = result.toFixed(2);
    }
}

function multiplyCost02() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('sqIn1').value;

    var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * 0.05;
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('2clr-Cost').value = result.toFixed(2);
    }
}

function sumJob() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('1clr-Cost').value;
      var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('2clr-Cost').value;

    var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('JobCost').value = '$'+ result.toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Always post your code in your question please. But to generally answer your question, what do you think `parseInt` does?

Comment: Thanks j08691. I added the code. But to "generally answer" my question, you cant ask a question. That does not help me. Being new to asking questions, I had a hard time even getting the code to show properly. That is why I though a simple JSBin link where it is all loacted would be okay.

Comment: SO doesn't approve of questions where the code exists solely on another site. In the event that that site goes away or becomes inaccessible, then your question would lose all value.

Comment: "But to "generally answer" my question, you cant ask a question." .. yes you can, that is the Socratic method in action.

Comment: don't get caught up in semantics....just look at what parseInt does

Comment: Thanks.
"Socratic" sounds awfully close to sarcastic which is how it came across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a two `parseInt` operations and adding them together, then getting the element.  `parseInt` will strip the two digits after the decimal.

**UPDATE**:

Try `parseFloat`

Comment: Thanks. would I replace **all** the `parseInt` with `parseFloat`? Or just the last set?

Comment: That is something you will have to consider for each function.  If the multiplication can allow decimals, then yes it would need to be `parseFloat` but if it is integer only, then no it can remain a `parseInt`.  The only one I know of for sure is in the `subJob` function.